# ClassCastException Beansbinding Java

Tags: java, user-interface, jtextfield, classcastexception, beans-binding

Can you tell me why I get `ClassCastException` exception here?

```
protected void initDataBindings() {
    BeanProperty<Apprentice, String> apprenticeBeanProperty = BeanProperty.create("vorname");
    ObjectProperty<JTextField> jTextFieldObjectProperty = ObjectProperty.create();
    AutoBinding<Apprentice, String, JTextField, JTextField> autoBinding = Bindings.createAutoBinding(UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, apprentice, apprenticeBeanProperty, txtVorname, jTextFieldObjectProperty);
    autoBinding.bind();
}
```

this is the textfield:

```
        {
            txtVorname = new JTextField();
            //txtVorname.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(txtVorname.getPreferredSize().width + 160, txtVorname.getPreferredSize().height));
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            rightPanel.add(txtVorname, gbc);
        }
```

and the *Apprentice.java* has the attributee "vorname" (german for firstname) which is private field with getters and setters.

```
private String vorname;

public Apprentice(){
    ;
}

public String getVorname() {
    return vorname;
}

public void setVorname(String vorname) {
    this.vorname = vorname;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by myself, I bound the "Self Object" instead of the "text" is has to look like this:

```
protected void initDataBindings() {
    BeanProperty<Apprentice, String> apprenticeBeanProperty_1 = BeanProperty.create("vorname");
    BeanProperty<JTextField, String> jTextFieldBeanProperty_1 = BeanProperty.create("text");
    AutoBinding<Apprentice, String, JTextField, String> autoBinding_1 = Bindings.createAutoBinding(UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, apprentice, apprenticeBeanProperty_1, txtVorname, jTextFieldBeanProperty_1);
    autoBinding_1.bind();
}
```

Thanks anyway :)